# Laravel pass data between views

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a view with a few variables that I want to pass to a new page and prepopulate a form with them.

```
$data->title
$data->catid
$data->category
$data->groupName
```

The "vanila way I could make a url like something.com?var1=something&var2=something etc.

But how can I do this in laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you can redirect to a page with GET parameter. For example, "something.com?var1=something&var2=something", You can actually pass this data to another view in Laravel. Let's assume you want to pass `var1` and `var2` variables to another view.

You will redirect user to the URL containing two variables as `GET` parameters, You will also execute Controller function that will handle that route. Let's assume that following is your **web.php or routes.php** file.

```
Route::get('firstpage","SomeController@view1");
Route::get("secondpage","SomeController@view2");
```

Now, in `view2` method of the `SomeController`, You can check if those variables exist or not. Here is an example of `var1` and `var2`.

```
public function view2()
{
    if(isset($_GET['var1'])){
        $var1 = $_GET['var1'];
    }

    // Similar for var2
}
```

This is how you can pass variables between views.

Answer (score 0):

The best way IMHO is using [sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session).

```
session()->put('data', $data);
```

And to retrieve it and to check if the key exists:

```
if (session()->has('data')) {
    $data = session('data'); //array
}
```

If you use the $data in session() only once you can pull it `session()->pull('data'); //array`

A word of caution if you use database sessions. You may have to change the field 'payload' from TEXT to MEDIUMTEXT if $data holds larger amounts of data.

The use of sessions is not search engine (SEO) friendly. If that matters, the easiest way to make the url is `$str = http_build_query($data);` and to build the url `\URL()->route('your.route').'?'.$str;`

To access the data from the URL: `$title = \Request::query('title');`